# New Google Maps preview with javascript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to embed the new google maps https://www.google.com/maps/preview that is much more fluid with zoom and pan operations on a web using Javascript API v3. So far I could not do it.
Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

```
google.maps.visualRefresh=true;
```

more info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-refresh